# What happens if my middle name is my last name on my airline ticket?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, airlines

I am traveling JetBlue to go to Florida from Massachussets and I realized after receiving my confirmation code that instead of my name going first-middle-last it goes -first-last-middle ... will this be a problem? I already contacted them but they have not emailed me back. Everything is spelt correctly there is just a mismatch of my name. Should I worry about not being able to board? My flight is about a month away so I'm trying to deal with it now.

Comment: Short answer: not a problem.

Comment: This likely WILL be a problem.  If your middle name is the in last name field then the TSA "Secure Flight" data is wrong.  Call JetBlue and get it fixed.  If it's still within 24 hours then you can probably just cancel the ticket and reboot it which might be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can ring jet blue and get this changed.

Correcting Minor Booking Errors
If you need to correct a minor error you made while booking online (i.e. misspelled names, typos, wrong mailing address/phone number/email address), please call one of our Reservations crewmembers at 1-800-JETBLUE(538-2583) with your confirmation number for assistance.

http://help.jetblue.com/SRVS/CGI-BIN/webisapi.dll/,/?St=169,E=0000000000046022254,K=8434,Sxi=5,Case=obj%282926%29#s2